# Explanation on Spring Controller format

Tags: spring, controller

```
/**  
 * @param model
 * @param condition
 * @param maps
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */

@RequestMapping(value="/encodeGrp")
public String encodeGrp(
        HttpServletResponse response,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        ModelMap model,
        Condition condition,
        @RequestParam Map<String, Object> maps) throws Exception {


      {       
        List<Encode> result = EncodeRepository.encGrpList(maps);

        model.addAttribute("result", result);
        model.addAttribute("maps", maps);
        model.addAttribute("condition", condition);

        model.addAttribute("grpNm2", maps.get("grpNm2"));

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        }                   

    return "admin/encMng/encode/encodeGrp";
```

So I have a few questions understanding this Contorller code in Spring

1) In this code,

```
public String encodeGrp(
        HttpServletResponse response,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        ModelMap model,
        Condition condition,
        @RequestParam Map<String, Object> maps) throws Exception {
```

I know they are using "Map" as a parameter for getting/setting data.
But what does

```
ModelMap model,
Condition condition,
```

mean? Are they using model and condition like "Map"?
If so, what is the difference with model,condition and Map?

2) In

```
model.addAttribute("result", result);
model.addAttribute("maps", maps);
model.addAttribute("condition", condition);
```

it means they are using "result" to get the data from result in jsp page, correct?

I am so confused here...can someone explain it to me?

Comment: What is the fully qualified name of `Condition`?

Comment: I think it is just Condition. Is that info necessary? If so, in what way?

Comment: Is it a custom class or something provided by Spring or any other library?

Comment: Condition is commonly used in Spring

Comment: for my project at least

Comment: What is the fully qualified class name?

Comment: fully qualified class name is "Condition"

Comment: So it's in the default package? I don't know of any Spring classes in the default package.

Comment: import groove.spring.data.domain.Condition;
--hope this code helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't know what that `Condition` class is. It's possibly being used as a model attribute.

As for [`ModelMap`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/ModelMap.html), its javadoc states

> Implementation of Map for use when building model data for use with UI
>   tools.

In Spring's MVC implementation, the `ModelMap` (and other `Model...` classes) serve as the intermediary for storing model elements between the controllers and the views.

Any attributes you store in a `ModelMap` will eventually find themselves in `HttpServletRequest` attributes, and this before the view is rendered. The purpose here is to add any objects you will need in your view but without having a dependency on the Servlet API.

In this code

```
model.addAttribute("result", result);
model.addAttribute("maps", maps);
model.addAttribute("condition", condition);
```

you're adding a number of model attributes so that they are available in a view, possibly a JSP.

Your `Map` parameter

```
@RequestParam Map<String, Object> maps)
```

is annotated with [`@RequestParam`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) which

> If the method parameter is Map or
>   MultiValueMap and a parameter name is not specified,
>   then the map parameter is populated with all request parameter names
>   and values.

(ignore the `<String, String>`, the same will happen with `<String, Object>`). Therefore, for this parameter, all request parameters will be bound to the `Map`.

Comment: Thanks, it really helps. One more question though. 
If the parameter name is specified as Condition or model, the data will be stored in Condition or model, right?

Comment: And if I don't state the parameter, then it automatically stores in Map. yeah?

Comment: @user2470075 Which parameter's name? And which data? Note that parameters are not typically related. So one doesn't prevent the other.